# Caching AlamofireImage responses to disk

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlcache, alamofireimage

I need a little help with AlamofireImages. In the app, tapping on a table view cell will download and set an image using the built in ImageView extension, seen below:

```
func sendImageRequest(imageView: UIImageView, item: CatalogItem, isLargeImage: Bool? = false){
    let imageURL = ImageManager.URLBuilder(sku: item.sku, largeImage: isLargeImage)

    // Clear the image so that recycled images are cleared.
    imageView.image = nil

    // Create the request and add the token string to the authorization header
    var urlRequest = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string: imageURL)!)
    urlRequest.setValue("Bearer \(ImageManager.getTokenString()!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    // If the token exists AND is VALID (not expired) - Get the image.
    if ImageManager.checkIfTokenExists() && ImageManager.checkTokenIsValid(){
        debugPrint("Valid token already exists. Fetching image... TableViewExtension")
        imageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: urlRequest){ response in
            switch response.result{
            case .success(let image):
                debugPrint(response)
                debugPrint("SUCCESS")
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                debugPrint("Error: \(error)")
                debugPrint(response.response)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    // Else if the token exists AND is INVALID (expired) - Delete the old token, get a new one, and fetch the image
    else if ImageManager.checkIfTokenExists() && !ImageManager.checkTokenIsValid(){
        debugPrint("Token expired... Getting new token.")
        ImageManager.deleteToken()
        let tokenRequest = NetRequest.newTokenRequest(url: "http://\(SettingsManager.KEY_ServerURL).ziizii.io/zz/jwt/new?service=images.ziizii.io")
        tokenRequest.requestJWTToken(){
            debugPrint("Token renewed. Fetching image...")
            imageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: urlRequest)
        }
    }
    // If the token doesn't exist, request a new one and fetch the image.
    else{
        debugPrint("Requesting new token...")
        let tokenRequest = NetRequest.newTokenRequest(url: "http://\(SettingsManager.KEY_ServerURL).ziizii.io/zz/jwt/new?service=images.ziizii.io")
        tokenRequest.requestJWTToken(){
            debugPrint("Token aquired. Fetching image...")
            imageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: urlRequest)
        }
    }
}
```

So, this part I'm alright with. It works, It caches the object to the disk and sets the ImageView image. If you tap it again later, it checks if the image is in the cache and if so, simply applies the image. Neat.

Now, a new requirement for the project is to give the user the ability to preload every image and cache them. Now I'm no longer using AFI ImageView extension, and instead using the Downloader. I'm unsure how to get the Downloader to:
A) Cache to the disk and
B) When a user taps a cell, have that ImageView extension check the same cache to see if it was preloaded and apply that image.

AFI is smart enough to check the cache for the image data before sending out the request, so I'm sure this is possible.

What I have so far for downloading the images is below:

```
static var downloader = ImageDownloader.default

static func downloadImage(urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible)
{
    self.downloader.download(urlRequest) { response in
        switch response.result{
        case .success(let image): // If successful, cache the image.
            print("SUCCESS")
            break
        case .failure(let error): // If unsuccessful, remove the cached 404 response and apply a nil image.
            print("ERROR: \(response.error)")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea how to accomplish this or any helpful tips or tricks, that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I assume that you are downloading the image from a string as a download url. I've dealt with the same problem; in my case, I wasn't using Alamofire, I was using an extension to the image view:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
```

extension UIImageView {

```
func downloadImage(from imgURL: String!) {

    self.image = nil

    // Check if there's an image in the cache 

    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: imgURL as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    // Otherwise, download image from Firebase via URL-string

    let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: imgURL as AnyObject)
            }
            self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

}

Now I solved the preload problem by simply calling

```
for i in objects { // whatever object you're having

   imageView.downloadImage(fromURL: i.url)

}
```

...in the viewDidLoad().

Now it loops through all custom objects downloading and caching all the images, and if the user taps on an image, it's instantly loaded from the cache. I hope this is helping you with your problem.

Comment: NSCache is not caching to disk, but rather to memory. The question was about caching to disk.